# Address already in use (bind failed)

Tags: java, linux, sockets, tcp, bind

I'm using these two java sources to exchange a file between 2 PC(linux and mac).
The problem is showed only on Linux.

I'm using these 2 codes in a thread where i recall more times.

But i have this error: **Address already in use (bind failed).**
I have searched on the web and on this forum that the problem is the TCP connection still active, so there is a function of the class Server Socket called **setReuseAddress(true)** which allows me to reuse the address. I call this function after the instantiation of ServerSocket but the problems persists.
How can i resolve this problem?

[EDIT]
Server

```
{

        final int SOCKET_PORT = 13267;
        final String FILE_TO_SEND = "/Users/jo/Desktop/cryptedSymmetric.key";
        boolean flag = true;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        ServerSocket servsock = null;
        Socket sock = null;

        try {
            servsock = new ServerSocket(); // create unbound ServerSocket
            servsock.setReuseAddress(true);
            servsock.bind(new InetSocketAddress(SOCKET_PORT));

            // while (flag) {
            System.out.println("SO_REUSEADDRESS is enabled: " + servsock.getReuseAddress());
            System.out.println("Waiting client B...");
            try {
                sock = servsock.accept();
                System.out.println("Connection : " + sock);
                // send file
                File myFile = new File(FILE_TO_SEND);
                byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
                fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                os = sock.getOutputStream();
                System.out.println("Invio del file " + FILE_TO_SEND + "(" + mybytearray.length + " bytes)");
                os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                os.flush();
                System.out.println("Done.");
                flag = false;
            } finally {
                if (bis != null)
                    bis.close();
                if (os != null)
                    os.close();
                if (sock != null)
                    sock.close();
            }
            // }
        } finally {
            if (servsock != null)
                servsock.close();

            return flag;
        }
    }
```

EDIT Client

```
{
        int SOCKET_PORT = 0;
        SOCKET_PORT = 13267;
        // final String SERVER = "192.168.1.2";
        final String FILE_TO_RECEIVED = "/Users/jo/Desktop/publicB.key";
        final int FILE_SIZE = 6022386;
        boolean flag = true;

        int bytesRead;
        int current = 0;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
        Socket sock = null;
        try {
            sock = new Socket(address.getHostAddress(), SOCKET_PORT);
            System.out.println("Connessione...");

            // receive file
            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[FILE_SIZE];
            InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
            fos = new FileOutputStream(FILE_TO_RECEIVED);
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            // bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            // current = bytesRead;
            int count;
            while ((count = is.read(mybytearray)) > 0) {
                bos.write(mybytearray, 0, count);
            }



            bos.flush();
            System.out.println("File " + FILE_TO_RECEIVED + " scaricato (" + current + " bytes letti)");
            flag = false;
        } finally {
            if (fos != null)
                fos.close();
            if (bos != null)
                bos.close();
            if (sock != null)
                sock.close();

            return flag;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I call this function after the instantiation of ServerSocket but the problems persists.

That's because you called it too late. You should have observed that the exception was thrown before the call. You need to separate creation from binding:

```
servsock = new ServerSocket(); // create unbound ServerSocket
servsock.setReuseAddress(true);
servsock.bind(new InetSocketAddress(SOCKET_PORT));
```

NB your copy code should be the same at both ends, and not like either version you've used, which exhibit various problems and fallacies:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Comment: i've modified the code (copy code(client) and server) but the problem persists, Can you see the new code EJP? It works at the first time, but the second time not. I followed your instructions.....

Comment: Are you trying to create *two* of them ? You can't do that.

Comment: I have to send a file (the key) from A to B and B has to send to A its key. So i've created 2 connections (because i don't know very well the mechanism). It works for the first time, but when i restart the thread i have this problem ONLY on LINUX (because the port is still opened)

Comment: If you're closing and reopening the server socket, don't. Leave it open or the life of the process.

Comment: I have a mac and a laptop. In the first time i send the file from laptop to mac (mac is client and laptop is server). I close the connection and in the second time laptop is client and mac is server, so the mac sends the file to the laptom ( is an exchange of files). So after this job, i need to restart the thread where this methods are called...but it doesn't work...on the mac there isn't this problem but on linux yes and i see the error. Is there a possibility to use only one connection and exchange files like a peer to peer connection?

Comment: Yes, of course, but the simple solution iis contained n my last comment.